# php show data from an array in an order instead of random

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am showing data from an array in random using rand()  . Is it possible to show the data in a systematic order instead of random ?

```
$one = data1;
$two = data2;
$three = data3;
$myarray = array($one, $two, $three)
$show = $myarray[rand(0,2)];
```

Note the $show variable is called dynamically in page & it outputs values of $myarray at many places on page

Ex. It outputs above array in random orders as data2,data1,data3,data3,data2,data1......

How do i code the above so that the result on page will be in a systematic order i.e.
first to be shown will be the 1st value of array i.e. data1
then data2 then data3 then again data1 then data2 then data3 & so on...

Comment: Do you mean to display those values on the same page/same request, or between different requests?

Comment: Jeto , i want to display it on same page , the array is actually group of 3 urls which get dynamically attached to external links as prefix  via a custom wordpress function which identifies external urls then uses above code of rand() function to attach prefix to the external urls . So on one page we can have 50 external urls and on some pages  just 10 external  urls . These array of 3 url prefix to those external links ..but the rand() is not in order we want order like  1st url will have $one , next one has $two , 3rd one has $three, 4th one has $one and thus in order...

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of a [`InfiniteIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.infiniteiterator.php) for this purpose. It iterates normally then loops back over to the beginning and so on.

It also uses [`static` variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) to retain state across subsequent calls.

This becomes:

```
add_action('mycustomlink', function ($link) {
  if ($link->is_external()) {
    $externalUrl = $link->get_attr('href');

    static $urls = [
      'https://example1.com?=',
      'https://example2.com?=',
      'https://example3.com?='
    ];

    /** @var Iterator $urlsIterator */
    static $urlsIterator;

    if (!isset($urlsIterator)) {
      $urlsIterator = new \InfiniteIterator(new \ArrayIterator($urls));
      $urlsIterator->rewind();
      $url = $urlsIterator->current();
    } else {
      $urlsIterator->next();
      $url = $urlsIterator->current();
    }

    $link->set_attr('href', $url . $externalUrl);
  }
}, 10, 1);
```

Note that I took the liberty of refactor your code to be more PHP7-friendly syntax while I was at it.

**Demo (of the function): https://3v4l.org/sq2Gk**

Comment: Jeto , the parameter to identify external urls in any pages is lets say `$exturl` and final dyanmic url is called just once at the end of code `$finalurl = $show.$exturl;`  [$show is from my code above] . This `$finalurl` is written once in the code & it replaces all `$exturl` in pages with `$finalurl`   how will be able to use Iterator once just like `rand()`  to get the orderly output ?? because i cant call the `$url` of your code many times in my code

Comment: @Martin Sorry, I don't really follow. Please edit your question with more precise samples resembling what you have right now. It's a bit too obscure at the moment.

Comment: Jeto, i have edited the question with detailed example, please check now.

Comment: Jeto it doesnt seem to work in wordpress installation but in php example you gave it works.  We cant touch following part of code which is needed by a plugin which does the prefixing action  [please see Edit 2 for part of code which we should not edit & one which we can edit]

Comment: @Martin Ah sorry I actually meant to change it back to the way it was but forgot. Edited my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a session variable to save the array index, which you increment each time.

```
session_start();
$one = data1;
$two = data2;
$three = data3;
$myarray = array($one, $two, $three)
if (isset($_SESSION['myarray_index'])) {
    // increment with wraparound
    $myarray_index = ($_SESSION['myarray_index'] + 1) % count($myarray);
} else {
    $myarray_index = 0;
}
$_SESSION['myarray_index'] = $myarray_index;
$show = $myarray[$myarray_index];
```